# Robocopy: Why you no include same?

Tags: robocopy

So here's my script:

```
robocopy  X:\WebApplications\Harrier\Stage X:\WebApplications\Harrier\production /is /e   /xf: web.config
robocopy  X:\WebApplications\Osprey\Stage X:\WebApplications\Osprey\production /is /e /xf: web.config
```

One would expect that every file in stage would be copied to production, including files that appear to be the same, but excluding the web.config.

This script will happily skip files it deems to be the same, ignoring the /is argument.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you establish that it is skipping the files?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz:  it says "49 SKIPPED."  I know, it is bizarre.

Comment: you have a space between /xf: and web.config. typo ?

Answer (score 0):

Testing this myself, it actually copies the file. but it does go VERY fast.

comparing the output of the command with the /is switch and without the following shows in the summary (dutch version of windows):

With the switch:

```
              TotaalGekopieerdOvergeslagenNiet gelijk   Mislukt   Extra's
   Mappen:         2         0         2         0         0         0
Bestanden:       111       111         0         0         0         0
    Bytes:   27.39 m   27.39 m         0         0         0         0
   Aantal:   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
```

Without the switch:

```
              TotaalGekopieerdOvergeslagenNiet gelijk   Mislukt   Extra's
   Mappen:         2         0         2         0         0         0
Bestanden:       111         0       111         0         0         0
    Bytes:   27.39 m         0   27.39 m         0         0         0
   Aantal:   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
```